# wso2-esb After clustering, every carbon console(management and worker) doesn't work

Tags: nginx, cluster-computing, wso2, wso2-esb

I used the [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+ESB) to create ESB  cluster with one management node and worker node  (in one server) and one worker node in another server. I did the same thing in the reference. And it shows that "Member Joined" message. But i cannot load the carbon console in my web browser using https://mgt.esb.wso2.com:9443/carbon. I'm using NginX load balancer. And i have confused with how can the 4500 port is related with NginX load balancer.

Comment: In your case, 4500 port is used for cluster node inter communication, and you don't need to load balance traffic on that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by doesn't work. Any logs.

TCP ports such as 4500 mentioned the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+ESB) is nothing to do with load balancing stuff. Those ports are used to communicate between the clustering nodes.

ELB is a WSO2 product, so as for the documentation when we configure the worker node we configure the ELB also as a cluster node in the cluster.

If you are using the Nginx as a load balancer this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+ESB+4.9.0) will give you the better understanding.